# Sitecore PowerShell Show-ListView Expression only want the date

Tags: powershell, sitecore

Have a Powershell script and it's reading through bucketed items getting various properties on the item (which happen to be documents).  The "__Reminder Date" field is a date/time field but only want to display the date portion of the field in the output rather than the date and time.  What is the method/function to get just the date?  Thanks!!

```
cd "master:\content\Intranet\data\Document Library"

get-childitem -recurse `
| where-object { $_.TemplateName -match "DocumentItem" -and  $_."File Category" -match "Teaching Sheets" } `
| Sort "__Reminder Date" |
Show-ListView -property `
    @{ Name="Document Name"; Expression={$_.Name}},
    @{ Name="Public Site Enabled"; Expression={$_.PublicSiteEnabled}},
    @{ Name="Reminder Text"; Expression={$_."__Reminder Text"}},
    @{ Name="Reminder Date"; Expression={$_."__Reminder Date"}},
    @{ Name="File Category"; Expression={$_."File Category"}} `
    -Title "Childrens's Hospital of Wisconsin" `
    -InfoTitle "Report showing Teaching Sheets review date" `
    -Modal -Width 960 -Height 640 -PageSize 200
Show-Result -Text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After poking around and taking a little different thought process on this, I found the answer.  Isn't that the way it goes...  Here's the answer, plus I figured out a way to get True and False for the boolean property on the "PublicSiteEnabled" field.

```
cd "master:\content\Intranet\data\Document Library"

get-childitem -recurse `
| where-object { $_.TemplateName -match "DocumentItem" -and  $_."File Category" -match "Teaching Sheets" } `
| Sort "__Reminder Date" |
Show-ListView -property `
    @{ Name="Document Name"; Expression={$_.Name}},
    @{ Name="Public Site Enabled"; Expression={switch($_.PublicSiteEnabled) { 0 {"False"; break} default {"True"; break}}}},
    @{ Name="Reminder Text"; Expression={$_."__Reminder Text"}},
    @{ Name="Reminder Date"; Expression={Get-Date -format "MM/dd/yyyy" $_."__Reminder Date"}},
    @{ Name="File Category"; Expression={$_."File Category"}} `
    -Title "Childrens's Hospital of Wisconsin" `
    -InfoTitle "Report showing Teaching Sheets review date" `
    -Modal -Width 960 -Height 640 -PageSize 200
Show-Result -Text
```

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. Check out Sitecore.stackexchange.com when you get a chance.